# Visual Studio 2010 Database Project Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, database-project

In Visual Studio 2010, it's possible to create "deployment packages" for your projects. For web applications, you can right-click the project, and choose "Build Deployment Package"

However for "Database Projects", there is no "Build Deployment Package" option. There's "Build", and "Deploy". When you check the properties of a Database project, under the "Deploy" tab, you can create a deployment script. This is supposed to generate a **create-database.sql** script that some DBA on another team can run and deploy your database (synonymous with an IT person importing a deployment package for a web application into IIS)

But when I build my solution, including the database project, I don't see the create-database.sql script anywhere? What's going on here? Why is the database deployment different than web application deployment?

What is the deployment process supposed to be?

Comment: ... because databases aren't the same as web sites, and because dbas aren't the same as anyone else.

Comment: ok, so what is the deployment process here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment script isn't created when you build the solution.  You need to select 'Deploy' from the build menu, then the script will be created according to your project settings.

Comment: but doesn't that also deploy the database to the database server? What about if you have a separate team that handles deployments? How do they fit into this process?

Comment: No, you can set the deployment action to generate a script, or to generate a script and deploy it to the target server.  If you just generate the script, you can then send it to your DBAs for review and deployment.

Comment: ahhhhh, that's what I was missing! the "Deploy" action is connected to whether or not you specify "generate script", or "generate script and deploy". The wording was confusing me! Awesome! Thanks

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that the build process will produce the .dbschema file; you can then use VSDBCMD from the command line to deploy the same bits to different servers. Each time, it will produce a different change script based on which database you're deploying to.